# Sending nmap output to a file without also printing it to standard output

Tags: shell, arguments, nmap

I am invoking `nmap` with the following command:

```
nmap -oX i.xml -p 1-1023 -r -T4 -d -d
```

Doing this sends output to `i.xml` successfully. However, text is still printed on the command line in additional being redirected to `i.xml`. I would like the command to run silently on the command line, but to still write all of its output to my `i.xml` file. I tried using the `-v0` argument, but using it results in neither my XML file nor the command line seeing any output.

How can I tell nmap to send its output *only* to my XML file?

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried redirecting stdout to the null device?

```
nmap -oX i.xml -p 1-1023 -r -T4 -d -d >/dev/null
```

On Windows, use `NUL` instead of `/dev/null`

Comment: I just attempted it. The xml file doesn't get made.

Comment: What version of Nmap are you running? This should work (and does on my installation)

Comment: It works for me as well, can you provide us information on your os and nmap version?

Comment: Nmap version 5.51  and Windows 7 64bit. I feel I should also mention that I run nmap through python using the command os.system("nmap -oX i.xml -p 1-1023 -r -T4 -d -d")

Comment: Sorry, I'd assumed you were using Linux or UNIX. I've added a note on how to reference the null device on Windows. That should work from the Windows command line, but there may be complications when that is done inside of a Python call to os.system(), so you may need to use Python's stdout redirection options instead if you're still not getting the desired behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First, you didn't specified any target on your command line. Not sure what you intend to do
Second, -oX i.xml will output to i.xml AND stdout
To have results only on xml file (and not on stdout), add an extra -v0 parameter